# How to get not found and permission errors from popen

Tags: c++, popen

I made a small program that just executes scripts from C++. And a parse all the outputs using `fgets`. However whenever it does not find the script or it does not have the execute right, `popen` (that I us to get the `FILE*` for `fgets`) report the error, but I can't seem to pick it up.

I want to get the perrmission/not found errors from `popen`. Now I have tried both [errno](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) and [ferror](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ferror/), both however does not seem to give me any indication that something is wrong

```cpp
bool ScriptDL::script_exec(const std::string& cmd) {
    std::array<char, 256> buffer;
    std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&pclose)> pipe(popen(cmd,data(), "r"), close);
    std::cout << "sys Error:" << strerror(errno) << "\n";
    if (ferror(pipe.get())) {
        perror("Error: ");
    }
    if (!pipe) {
        return false;
    }
    while (fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), pipe.get()) != nullptr) {
        //Does stuff with output
    }
    return true;
}
```

Output from non-existing script:

```
sh: 1: ./script.sh: not found
sys Error:Success
```

Output from existing script without execute set:

```
sh: 1: ./script.sh: Permission denied
sys Error:Success
```

The `sh: 1 ....`  comes from open, that I can't seem to access and parse

Comment: Is the script in the process [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory)? If you use an absolute path to the script, does it work then?

Comment: `popen` is not a proper way to control a child process or read output from it. It launches shell and lets the shell execute command therefore under normal conditions it does not fail or return exit code of the executed command. Use boost.process instead

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I mean, I can get the script to work, I just want to parse the error message, when a user point to a non-existing script, or the script does not have execute rights

Comment: Did you try something like `FILE* fcmd = popen(...)` and then check the value of `fcmd`? (for test only).

Comment: If you're on a POSIX system (like Linux or macOS) I recommend you implement your own `popen` call using `fork`, `pipe` and `exec`. Then you can capture both standard output as well as standard error from the child process.

Comment: On a different note, is `cmd` containing a "command" input from a user? That's a pretty big security risk unless you do some thorough input validation and sandboxing of the command.

Comment: @Damien I mean the variable `pipe` is a  `unique_ptr` to `FILE` so using `pipe.get()` should give me the `FILE *`. But I did try your suggestion, but it yielded no different results

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the security headups, atm the the `cmd` is 2 part. 1 is the script it runs, that is set by me, and can't be changed, and the arguments to the script, which is not validated.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude For the POSIX system, it needs to run on both POSIX, and Windows, so currently I have a `#ifdef _WIN32` where it uses `_popen` instead of `popen` I can make my own `popen` call, but atm the effort is probably not worth it